# How to resolve Concatenation Exception with LISTAGG Function?

Tags: sql, oracle12c, listagg

Hi I am trying to execute the below query which uses LISTAGG function. The query gives the result but when I try to pull more records from grid or when I try to get the count of the records it gives me error : ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long.

Query:

```
 SELECT  sceng_eng_id AS eng_id,
    SUBSTRB(LISTAGG(sceng_pr_eid, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sceng_eng_id,sceng_pr_eid),1,100) secengs,
    SUBSTR(LISTAGG(sceng_eng_nme, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sceng_eng_id,sceng_pr_eid),1,256) secengnme
        FROM seceng group by sceng_eng_id
```

Any help would be really Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Two things are going on.  First, Oracle limits the length of strings to 2,000 characters.  Second, Oracle often returns rows as they become available rather than generating the entire result set.

So, I suspect that the first few rows are fine -- the resulting strings first comfortably in the limit.  However, as the engine goes through the data, it stumbles across a bad row.

You can find out which values are causing this using:

```
select ceng_eng_id AS eng_id, sum(len(sceng_pr_eid) + 1), sum(len(sceng_eng_nme) + 1)
from t
group by ceng_eng_id
having sum(len(sceng_pr_eid) + 1) >= 2000 or 
       sum(len(sceng_eng_nme) + 1) >= 2000;
```

It is not clear what you want to do; perhaps you can fix the data or there might be other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the error by using ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...' which will cut your resulting string before the limit is reached. But please note it will be cut in this case.

```
SELECT  sceng_eng_id AS eng_id,
    SUBSTRB(LISTAGG(sceng_pr_eid, ','ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sceng_eng_id,sceng_pr_eid),1,100) secengs,
    SUBSTR(LISTAGG(sceng_eng_nme, ',' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sceng_eng_id,sceng_pr_eid),1,256) secengnme
        FROM seceng group by sceng_eng_id
```